# RxJava create consumer unsafe

Tags: rx-java

I am new to RX java.

Tried to create a consumer using a subscriber, but I saw that the create method is deprecated.

I saw that almost all other create methods, except the one with the Emitter class, use this unsafe method.

What does it mean "unsafe" and what is the difference between this and the one with the emitter. Should I not use this?

```
  @Deprecated
    public static <T> Observable<T> create(OnSubscribe<T> f) {
        return new Observable<T>(RxJavaHooks.onCreate(f));
    }

  @Experimental
    public static <T> Observable<T> unsafeCreate(OnSubscribe<T> f) {
        return new Observable<T>(RxJavaHooks.onCreate(f));
    }
```

**EDIT**:

How can I change something like this (ofcourse I simplified it):
I am trying to create an Observable that is created from a remote HTTP service.

```
return Observable.unsafeCreate(subscriber -> {
  HttpEntity entity = restTemplate.get(...)
    if (entity.status != 200) {
            subscriber.onError(new RunTimeException("Error");
    }
    else {
       Object object = createObject(entity)
       subscriber.onNext(object);
       subscriber.onCompleted();
    }
 });
```

Regards, Ido

Answer (score 2):

> What does it mean "unsafe"

Unsafe means that you need advanced RxJava knowledge to implement operators via `create` or `unsafeCreate`, which is not recommended anyway.

The `create` method was a very early way to create RxJava internal operators and had to be public in order to have it working across packages. Unfortunately, many found this method and started implementing basic sources instead and then wondered why their implementation failed. We couldn't remove the method because of binary compatibility and for those who used it properly.

> what is the difference between this and the one with the emitter

The emitter version sets up unsubscription properly and forces the developer to specify a backpressure strategy, which was typically not considered with the original `create` causing `MissingBackpressureException`.

> Should I not use this?

Since you are new to RxJava, you shouldn't use `create(OnSubscribe)` or `unsafeCreate(OnSubscribe)`. Also consider learning RxJava v2 instead where there is no unsafe create anymore.

Comment: Thanks.. I edited my post and added a code snippet.  How can I get data from a remote HTTP service correctly?

Comment: Wait, RxJava 2 does have **Observable.unsafeCreate**

Comment: @IdoBarash I want to learn that if onNext() method works on background thread or not? Do you have any idea about that? Thanks